# Is it possible to offer Apple's In App Purchases on an app that offers multiple user log-ins

Tags: ios, ipad, in-app-purchase, app-store

We're designing an iPad app at the moment which offers in-app purchases for non-consumable items.

As the scope of the project has expanded, we want to allow the option to sign in to an account, and then sign out of that account and into another - similar to how one could on an app like the Facebook app.

My question is: is it possible to link Apple's in-app purchases to one of **our system's** user accounts, so that a User may sign in to a different device and access their purchases, but if another User signs in to *my* device, they cannot access my purchases (despite the device being signed in to my Apple ID)?

Any suggestions welcome

Answer (score 2):

All completed in app purchases are tied to the Apple ID that was used at the time of the transaction. Since non-consumable in app purchases can only be purchased once, you can't use those. So, the only option would be to use consumable in app purchases and keep track of which system user account made the purchase. You need to store those purchase records on an external server somewhere though, since Apple will have no way of telling you which purchase went to which of your internal users. If you lose that purchase history your users will have to buy the item again, and probably not be very happy.

Comment: So it's a non-consumable that's never actually "consumed"?

Comment: I would say it's a consumable that's used to give the current user credit for the purchase. You'll just have to let them buy it, then consume it immediately.